# How do I COUNT certain values as the same?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, mysql-5.7

This query gives me the following result set:

`SELECT color, CCOUNT(color) FROM Table GROUP BY color;`

```
color    | COUNT(color)
-----------------------
red      | 3
orange   | 1
blue     | 2
azure    | 2
sky-blue | 1
```

I would like a query that sums the counts of certain values, like so:

```
color                        | COUNT(color)
-------------------------------------------
red                          | 3
orange                       | 1
blues, just all of the blues | 5
```

One possibility that comes to mind is littering the whole query with duplicates of an ugly monstrosity of a `CASE` match, but I haven’t tried it yet because I hate that kind of code duplication. Do better ways exist?

Comment: You must have the list of possible `color` values which must be treated as `'just all of the blues'`. It may be a table `(color - base_color)`, dynamic relation (in CTE, for example) or hardcoded relation (in FIND_IN_SET operand, for example).

Comment: @Akina That’s what I meant by “ugly monstrosity of a `CASE` match.” Something like, `SELECT CASE WHEN color IN ("blue", "azure", "sky-blue") THEN "blues" ELSE color, COUNT(CASE WHEN color IN...`. 

Joining an extra table would certainly be cleaner, but it seems wasteful to have it just for the one query. There’s a lot in SQL I still have yet to learn, gonna have to look into the other things you mentioned—thanks!

Comment: *it seems wasteful to have it just for the one query.* Hardcoding is more wasteful from all sides.

Comment: @Akina Fair point.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the work

```
select 
  case 
    when color in ('blue', 'azure', 'sky-blue') then 'blues, just all of the blues'
    else color
  end as my_custom_color_naming,
  count(*)
from table
group by my_custom_color_naming;
```

You can replace the `in ('blue', 'azure', 'sky-blue')` part with a nested select from a table (or another source) that contain your blue definitions. But if it comes to that, then it will be better to just do a join

E.g.

```
select m.color_group, count(*)
from table t
join mappings m on t.color = m.color
group by m.color_group
```

or if you don't have a table, but have a list of mappings and you want it "prettier"

```
; with mappings as (
  select 'blue', 'blues' as color_group
    union
  select 'azure', 'blues' as color_group 
    union
  select 'sky-blue', 'blues' as color_group
)
select m.color_group, count(*)
from table t
join mappings m on t.color = m.color
group by m.color_group
```

*Maybe the vendor you are using would allow you for a bit nicer syntax, especially in the `union` part.*

P.S. Doesn't seem much better then the `case when` part.

Comment: I don't think you can refer to the alias in the `COUNT()` call. Just use `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Huh, somehow, `COUNT(*)` didn’t even occur to me as possible.

Comment: Source data example shows that SUM() instead of COUNT() must be used.

Comment: Not sure about that. The OP is doing group by and using `count` and so should I in my example